# Pass all arguments into array VBS

Tags: vbscript

I want to run jsx script and passing argument into array

```
Const psNeverShowDebugger = 1, psDebuggerOnError = 2, psBeforeRunning = 3

Dim appRef
Set appRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")

Dim infosDoc
infosDoc = Wscript.arguments()

Dim JSXFile
JSXFile = Wscript.arguments(0)

appRef.DoJavaScriptFile "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Presets\Scripts\"+JSXFile+".jsx", Array(infosDoc), psNeverShowDebugger
```

Im getting the first argument in JSXFile but not getting all arguments in infosDoc so im a bit confuse, if someone can help me!

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

`Wscript.Arguments` (without parenthesis) returns an array of arguments, i.e. if you need to pass it as an argument of another function you should call as

```
Set infosDoc = Wscript.Arguments
...
appRef.DoJavaScriptFile 
      "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Presets\Scripts\"+JSXFile+".jsx", 
      infosDoc, 
      psNeverShowDebugger
```

if you need to pass an array with the specific keys then

```
appRef.DoJavaScriptFile 
      "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Presets\Scripts\"+JSXFile+".jsx", 
      Array(infosDoc(1), infosDoc(2)), <-- custom array with 2nd and 3rd elements of infosDoc
      psNeverShowDebugger
```